# Retrieve unchanged data

Tags: php, doctrine

How can I get the Doctrine_Record's unchanged version of field data. For example;

```
echo $user->username; // Prints 'David'
$user->username = 'John';
echo $user->username; // Prints 'John'
```

How to get the pre-changed value (David)?

Comment: Just save it into a variable.

Comment: I need to check changed fields for a logging system. For example, User X changed the "news_category" field of News Id 3 to "Flash News".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$modified = $user->getModified(true);
```

or if you have access to protected fields:

```
if (in_array('username', $this->_modified)) {
    // username changed
}
```